# "modulo" meaning in context of Formal Methods.

Tags: terminology, solution-verification, formal-proofs, theorem-provers

I am a beginner in the field of Formal Methods in Computer Science.

In the literature, I often encounter phrases, such as "... **modulo** equation theory".

Example are:

1. [SMT solver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satisfiability_modulo_theories) -- "Satisfiability **Modulo** Theory"
2. [Tamarin Verifier](https://tamarin-prover.github.io/) -- Many papers including [this](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01622110/document) one states -- "Proofs are constructed using backward search
   with support for reasoning **modulo** equational theories."

What does the term "Modulo" mean in the above context?

The only meaning of modulo that I know of is in the context of [integer division and the remainder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation).

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_(jargon)

Comment: that is helpful and it gives some hints.

Comment: An SMT solver is sorta like a SAT solver, but not boolean.