# meaning of “modulo” in Formal Methods.

Tags: formal-proofs, theorem-provers

[related to this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3539100/modulo-meaning-in-context-of-formal-methods)

What is meaning of **modulo** specifically in the context of [Tamarin prover](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01622110/document): "Proofs are constructed using backward search with support for reasoning **modulo** equational theories."

Comment: In this context, "modulo" can be taken as "with respect to" or, more precisely, "subject to the constraints of a given equational theory".

Comment: This is an informal use of the term "modulo" by analogy with the precise use of the term in number theory where $x \equiv y (\mbox{modulo}\, n)$, means that $x$ and $y$ differ by a multiple of $n$. What they mean is that their backward search process considers formulas that are equivalent in the equational theories in question to be the same.